# How to move the input phone field right next to the select country field? (bootstrap, css)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, express-handlebars

[image]

```
<div class="col-6">
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
        <select id="country" onchange="country_code()" style="height: 58px; width: 300px; border-radius: 5px;">
                        <option value="select country">select country</option> 
                        <option value="AF">Afghanistan (+93)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AL" value="355">Albania (+355)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="DZ" value="213">Algeria (+213)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AS" value="1684">American Samoa (+1684)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AD" value="376">Andorra (+376)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AO" value="244">Angola (+244)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AI" value="1264">Anguilla (+1264)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AQ" value="672">Antartica (+672)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AG" value="1268">Antigua &amp; Barbuda (+1268)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AR" value="54">Argentina (+54)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AM" value="374">Armenia (+374)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AW" value="297">Aruba (+297)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AU" value="61">Australia (+61)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AT" value="43">Austria (+43)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AZ" value="994">Azerbaijan (+994)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BS" value="1242">Bahamas (+1242)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BH" value="973">Bahrain (+973)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BD" value="880">Bangladesh (+880)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BB" value="1246">Barbados (+1246)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BY" value="375">Belarus (+375)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BE" value="32">Belgium (+32)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BZ" value="501">Belize (+501)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BJ" value="229">Benin (+229)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BM" value="1441">Bermuda (+1441)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BT" value="975">Bhutan (+975)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BO" value="591">Bolivia (+591)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BA" value="387">Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina (+387)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BW" value="267">Botswana (+267)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BR" value="55">Brazil (+55)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="IO" value="246">British India Ocean Terrirory (+246)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="VG" value="1284">British Virgin Islands (+1284)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BN" value="673">Brunei (+673)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BG" value="359">Bulgaria (+359)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BF" value="226">Burkina Faso (+226)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BI" value="257">Burundi (+257)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="KH" value="855">Cambodia (+855)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CM" value="237">Cameroon (+237)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CA" value="1">Canada (+1)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CV" value="238">Cape Verde Islands (+238)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="KY" value="1345">Cayman Islands (+1345)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CF" value="236">Central African Republic (+236)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TD" value="235">Chad (+235)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CL" value="56">Chile (+56)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CN" value="86">China (+86)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CX" value="61">Christmas Island (+61)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CC" value="61">Cocos Islands (+61)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CO" value="57">Colombia (+57)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="KM" value="269">Comoros (+269)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CK" value="682">Cook Islands (+682)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CR" value="506">Costa Rica (+506)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="HR" value="385">Croatia (+385)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CU" value="53">Cuba (+53)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CW" value="599">Curacao (+599)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CY" value="90">Cyprus - North (+90)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CY" value="357">Cyprus - South (+357)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CZ" value="420">Czech Republic (+420)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CD" value="243">Democratic Republic of Congo (+243)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="DK" value="45">Denmark (+45)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="DJ" value="253">Djibouti (+253)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="DM" value="1809">Dominica (+1809)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="DO" value="1809">Dominican Republic (+1809)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TL" value="670">East Timor (+670)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="EC" value="593">Ecuador (+593)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="EG" value="20">Egypt (+20)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SV" value="503">El Salvador (+503)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GQ" value="240">Equatorial Guinea (+240)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="ER" value="291">Eritrea (+291)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="EE" value="372">Estonia (+372)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="ET" value="251">Ethiopia (+251)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="FK" value="500">Falkland Islands (+500)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="FO" value="298">Faroe Islands (+298)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="FJ" value="679">Fiji (+679)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="FI" value="358">Finland (+358)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="FR" value="33">France (+33)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GF" value="594">French Guiana (+594)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PF" value="689">French Polynesia (+689)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GA" value="241">Gabon (+241)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GM" value="220">Gambia (+220)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GE" value="7880">Georgia (+7880)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="DE" value="49">Germany (+49)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GH" value="233">Ghana (+233)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GI" value="350">Gibraltar (+350)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GR" value="30">Greece (+30)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GL" value="299">Greenland (+299)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GD" value="1473">Grenada (+1473)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GP" value="590">Guadeloupe (+590)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GU" value="671">Guam (+671)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GT" value="502">Guatemala (+502)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GG" value="44">Guernsey (+44)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GN" value="224">Guinea (+224)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GW" value="245">Guinea-Bissau (+245)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GY" value="592">Guyana (+592)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="HT" value="509">Haiti (+509)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="HN" value="504">Honduras (+504)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="HK" value="852">Hong Kong (+852)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="HU" value="36">Hungary (+36)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="IS" value="354">Iceland (+354)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India (+91)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="ID" value="62">Indonesia (+62)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="IR" value="98">Iran (+98)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="IQ" value="964">Iraq (+964)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="IE" value="353">Ireland (+353)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="IM" value="44">Isle of Man (+44)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="IL" value="972">Israel (+972)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="IT" value="39">Italy (+39)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CI" value="225">Ivory Coast (+225)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="JM" value="1876">Jamaica (+1876)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="JP" value="81">Japan (+81)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="JE" value="44">Jersey (+44)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="JO" value="962">Jordan (+962)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="KZ" value="7">Kazakhstan (+7)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="KE" value="254">Kenya (+254)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="KI" value="686">Kiribati (+686)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="XK" value="383">Kosovo (+383)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="KW" value="965">Kuwait (+965)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="KG" value="996">Kyrgyzstan (+996)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="LA" value="856">Laos (+856)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="LV" value="371">Latvia (+371)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="LB" value="961">Lebanon (+961)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="LS" value="266">Lesotho (+266)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="LR" value="231">Liberia (+231)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="LY" value="218">Libya (+218)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="LI" value="417">Liechtenstein (+417)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="LT" value="370">Lithuania (+370)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="LU" value="352">Luxembourg (+352)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MO" value="853">Macao (+853)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MK" value="389">Macedonia (+389)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MG" value="261">Madagascar (+261)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MW" value="265">Malawi (+265)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MY" value="60">Malaysia (+60)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MV" value="960">Maldives (+960)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="ML" value="223">Mali (+223)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MT" value="356">Malta (+356)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MH" value="692">Marshall Islands (+692)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MQ" value="596">Martinique (+596)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MR" value="222">Mauritania (+222)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="YT" value="269">Mayotte (+269)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MX" value="52">Mexico (+52)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="FM" value="691">Micronesia (+691)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MD" value="373">Moldova (+373)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MC" value="377">Monaco (+377)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MN" value="976">Mongolia (+976)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="ME" value="382">Montengro (+382)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MS" value="1664">Montserrat (+1664)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MA" value="212">Morocco (+212)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MZ" value="258">Mozambique (+258)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MN" value="95">Myanmar (+95)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="NA" value="264">Namibia (+264)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="NR" value="674">Nauru (+674)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="NP" value="977">Nepal (+977)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="NL" value="31">Netherlands (+31)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AN" value="599">Netherlands Antilles (+599)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="NC" value="687">New Caledonia (+687)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="NZ" value="64">New Zealand (+64)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="NI" value="505">Nicaragua (+505)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="NE" value="227">Niger (+227)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="NG" value="234">Nigeria (+234)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="NU" value="683">Niue (+683)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="KP" value="850">North Korea (+850)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="NF" value="672">Norfolk Islands (+672)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="NP" value="670">Northern Marianas (+670)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="NO" value="47">Norway (+47)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="OM" value="968">Oman (+968)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PK" value="92">Pakistan (+92)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PW" value="680">Palau (+680)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PS" value="970">Palestine (+970)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PA" value="507">Panama (+507)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PG" value="675">Papua New Guinea (+675)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PY" value="595">Paraguay (+595)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PE" value="51">Peru (+51)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PH" value="63">Philippines (+63)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PN" value="64">Pitcairn (+64)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PL" value="48">Poland (+48)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PT" value="351">Portugal (+351)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PR" value="1787">Puerto Rico (+1787)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="QA" value="974">Qatar (+974)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CG" value="242">Republic of the Congo (+242)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="RE" value="262">Reunion (+262)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="RO" value="40">Romania (+40)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="RU" value="7">Russia (+7)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="RW" value="250">Rwanda (+250)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="BL" value="590">Saint Barthelemy (+590)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SH" value="290">Saint Helena (+290)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="KN" value="1869">Saint Kitts &amp; Nevis (+1869)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SC" value="1758">Saint Lucia (+1758)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SR" value="597">Suriname (+597)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="MF" value="590">Saint Martin (+590)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="PM" value="508">Saint Saint Pierre and Miquelon (+508)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="VC" value="1784">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines (+1784)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="WS" value="685">Samoa (+685)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SM" value="378">San Marino (+378)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="ST" value="239">Sao Tome &amp; Principe (+239)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SA" value="966">Saudi Arabia (+966)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SN" value="221">Senegal (+221)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CS" value="381">Serbia (+381)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SC" value="248">Seychelles (+248)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SL" value="232">Sierra Leone (+232)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SG" value="65">Singapore (+65)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SX" value="1721">Sint Maarten (+1721)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SK" value="421">Slovakia (+421)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SI" value="386">Slovenia (+386)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SB" value="677">Solomon Islands (+677)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SO" value="252">Somalia (+252)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="ZA" value="27">South Africa (+27)</option>  
                        <option data-countryCode="KR" value="82">South Korea (+82)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SS" value="211">South Sudan (+211)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="ES" value="34">Spain (+34)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="LK" value="94">Sri Lanka (+94)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SD" value="249">Sudan (+249)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SR" value="597">Suriname (+597)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SJ" value="47">Svalbard &amp; Jan Mayen (+47)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SZ" value="268">Swaziland (+268)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SE" value="46">Sweden (+46)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="CH" value="41">Switzerland (+41)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="SY" value="963">Syria (+963)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TW" value="886">Taiwan (+886)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TJ" value="992">Tajikistan (+992)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TZ" value="255">Tanzania (+255)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TH" value="66">Thailand (+66)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TG" value="228">Togo (+228)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TO" value="676">Tonga (+676)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TT" value="1868">Trinidad &amp; Tobago (+1868)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TN" value="216">Tunisia (+216)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TR" value="90">Turkey (+90)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TM" value="993">Turkmenistan (+993)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TC" value="1649">Turks &amp; Caicos Islands (+1649)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="TV" value="688">Tuvalu (+688)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="UG" value="256">Uganda (+256)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="UA" value="380">Ukraine (+380)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="AE" value="971">United Arab Emirates (+971)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">United Kingdom (+44)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">United States (+1)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="UY" value="598">Uruguay (+598)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="UZ" value="998">Uzbekistan (+998)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="VU" value="678">Vanuatu (+678)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="VA" value="379">Vatican City (+379)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="VE" value="58">Venezuela (+58)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="VN" value="84">Vietnam (+84)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="WF" value="681">Wallis &amp; Futuna (+681)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="YE" value="969">Yemen (North)(+969)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="YE" value="967">Yemen (South)(+967)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="ZM" value="260">Zambia (+260)</option>
                        <option data-countryCode="ZW" value="263">Zimbabwe (+263)</option>
        </select>
        </div>
<div class="form-floating mb-3" style="width: 300px;">
        <input type="tel" id="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" value="{{this.phone}}" name="phone" maxlength="12"/>
        <label for="floatingInput">Phone</label>
        {{!-- <script>
            var input = document.getElementById("phone");

input.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    if (!evt.ctrlKey && !evt.metaKey && !evt.altKey) {
        var charCode = (typeof evt.which == "undefined") ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
        if (charCode && !/\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(charCode))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
        </script> --}}
        <script>
            function country_code(){
                var val = document.getElementById("country").value;

                if (val === "select country") {
                    document.getElementById("output").value = "";
                }

                else if (val === "AF") {
                    document.getElementById("output").value = "+93";
                }
            }
        </script>  
</div>
</div>
```

Trying to move the input phone field right next to the select country field but can not. The code above is the code of the form. Both are inside in div class col-6, I can put them in two seperate classes col-3 but that will not then allow me to use the script tag to write the javascript code like in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSc-B54iVVo&ab_channel=DostoKaAdda

Comment: Can you try adding a `row` inside the `col-6`

<div class="col-6">
<div class='row'>
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
</div>
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Let me try and I will let you know

Comment: Still the same, didnt't work.

Answer (score 2):

Hi can you try adding a `row` inside the parent `col-6`?

```
<div class="col-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="form-floating mb-3"></div>
        <div class="form-floating mb-3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Then probably there is some extra margin or padding that's caused by the select which is pushing away the input. Can you check that?

Comment: Yes, the form floating width of select had the width on full and i did not set it. thank you very much.

Comment: So is it fixed now ?

Answer (score 1):

it's because Colum width is less than content(input field)
width try to reduce input field size and use

```
<div class="col-6" style='overflow: auto'>
.
.
<select id="country" onchange="country_code()" style="height: 58px; width: 200px; border-radius: 5px; float: left">
.
.
<div class="form-floating mb-3" style="width: 200px;float: left">
```

Comment: May I have more info about what to use?

Comment: sorry I didn't understand what you trying to say. can you explain

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-floating mb-3 d-flex align-items-center">
            <span class="me-3">Country</span>
        <select id="country" onchange="country_code()" style="height: 58px; width: 300px; border-radius: 5px;">
    <options />
        </select>
            </div>
            </div>
```